# Query an xml column from nhibernate 3.0

Tags: xml, nhibernate, xpath, xquery

I have a xml column in one of my entities
I mananged to use a user type and map this column to a property in my entity of type XmlElement.
I was wondering if I could query this object from the code like I do sql with QueryOver?
I found something like this [here](http://www.smelser.net/blog/post/2009/01/02/Hibernate-my-XML.aspx). But I don't understand exactly how to query it

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean query it in code ... or run the query in the db?

Comment: @Thilak Nathen, definetly query it in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this is how I did it evetually
not the preatiest code
but anyway ...
I combined the queryover with an sql restriction using the underlyingcriteria property
I needed to use a alias for the restriction because of a line in the nhibernate source code   that looks for an alias and gets the substring from begining to the alias
If you don't provide an alias obviously it fails

```
if (tagIds != null && tagIds.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder attrXPath = new StringBuilder();

                for(int counter = 0;counter<tagIds.Count();counter++)
                {
                    attrXPath.Append("@id=\"");
                    attrXPath.Append(tagIds[counter]);
                    attrXPath.Append("\"");
                    if(counter < tagIds.Count() - 1)
                        attrXPath.Append(" or ");
                }

                query.UnderlyingCriteria
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.SqlProjection("tags.exist('/tags/tag[" + attrXPath.ToString() + "]') as XmlRestriction",
                                                                    new string[] { "XmlRestriction" },
                                                                    new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String}), 1));
            }
```